# Laravel: create new project outgoing fron an old one

Tags: laravel, duplicates, project

How can I create a new project outgoing from an old one?  The generated APP_KEY should be different from the old key?

Could I copy the old project to another folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Thats what I do sometimes.

I first download a clean copy of Laravel, run `composer install` and `npm install`

Once I have all the dependencies (initial) pulled in, then I zip that folder.
This folder becomes my main "template".

So, anytime I need to run another project, I just extract the content of that folder into the new project.

Two things to run after (if you want to update the dependencies):

1. `composer update`
2. `npm update`

**Note that after installing Laravel for the first time, I do not touch the files, like the .env for instance. So, the new installation is actually new and ready for customisation.**

Comment: Thank you very much for this description.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Maybe you can accept the answer?